# Summing up values in columns up to a defined value for multiple year Jahre

Tags: python, insert, limit, cumsum

i have a datafram that looks like this:

[image]

It contains the Date, Year and the Mean Airtemperatur (T_mean) from **01.01.1937 to 31.12.2020.**

I want to sum the "T_mean" from **each year**. At the point where the "T_mean" reaches or crosses "**200**" I want to get the date where this happens.

So far I am able to sum "T_mean" with
`Sum_T_mean = np.cumsum(dataset['T_mean'])`

Unfortunately this sums ALL the "T_mean" from 1937 to 2020.

So I wanted to add a loop like this:

```
if i in dataset['Year'] == 1937:
    Sum_1937 = np.cumsum(dataset['T_mean'])
```

and add a new column with the Sum of T_mean from 1937 with:

```
dataset.insert(3, "Sum_1937", Sum_1937, allow_duplicates=False)
```

This does not work either.

If the codes would work I would be able to print the Date where for example "Sum_1937" reaches or crosses 200 with:

```
limit = 200
1937_over = dataset[dataset['Sum_1937'] >= limit]
1937_over.head(1)
```

Of course it is not the most elegant way because I need to repeat it for every year but so far I am not able to find a quicker way.

Thanks for any tips!

To create a small data frame you can use:

```
Date = [19370101, 19370102, 19370103, 19370104, 19370105, 19370106]
Year = [1937, 1937, 1937, 1937, 1937, 1937]
T_mean = [5.8, 5.6, 9.2, 8.0, 4.3, 6.4]

df = pd.DataFrame(Date, columns = ['Date'])
df.insert(1, "Year", Year, allow_duplicates=False)
df.insert(2, "T_mean", T_mean, allow_duplicates=False)
```

My desired output should look like this:
[image]

I would like to add a column for every year (1937-2020) to calculate the point where T_mean of each year reaches or crosses 200.

Comment: It would be nice of you to provide a sample dataframe in a form that I don't have to type in by hand.

Comment: Anyway, `df.groupby('Year')['T_mean'].transform('cumsum')`?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code.

Comment: I added a code to my question to create a sample dataframe  :)

Comment: You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Please give us a small Dataframe, with max 6 rows, no random values, and the desired output for this dataframe.

Comment: Also, what happened to the `'Year'` column in your sample df?

Comment: I am sorry. Hope my edit is better now.